# How to install spacemacs with company firewall

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am a vim user and completely new to Emacs. My company doesn't support a good python IDE and I decide to change to spacemacs (installing vim tool will require too many access to github.)

The company firewall exists so I also can't find a regular way to install spacemacs without using github. A company firewall exists for most large companies. So a way to setup spacemacs in the presence of a firewall is important.

I have tried several methods of installing spacemacs but none of them work. I am desperate to install spacemacs on my company's linux and the company doesn't have access to github (at least I can't figure out a way to build a proxy to git). I download spacemacs from http://spacemacs.org/ and unzip the file to `~/.emacs.d`.

Then I tried emacs --insecure, all the 90 packages cannot be installed：
The error messages are: Packages xx is not available. 
If I use emacs --debug-init, then the messages are: 
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (No such file or directory "bind-map" require(bind_map) )

I also set the proxy in the init.el so emacs can （May) have access to internet:

```
 (setq url-proxy-services '(("no_proxy" . "work\\.com")
                       ("http" . "proxy.work.com:911")))
```

Comment: As a stopgap, until a real solution is found, you could get spacemacs up and running at home and take a copy of ~/.emacs.d to work with you on a flash drive.